# writing feature descriptions in excel sheet in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

I have extracted corner points using detectMinEigenFeatures and then have extracted the feature descriptions using extractFeatures. Now I want to write the feature description in an excel sheet. But I can't write. When I use xlswrite it shows an error mentioning only numeric and logical matrices can be written in excel. Can any one suggest me a way to store the feature points in excel?

Comment: what the feature points' type?

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard to write the contents of a `binaryFeatures` object into an excel sheet. Each descriptor is a string of bits, not a vector of numeric values.